# Send array value in radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have multiple array buttons, and i need to send the value as array instead of string. Is that possible ?

This is my array format:

```
['2022-02-02','2022-02-08']
```

This is my radio button:

```
{% for data in date %}
<input type="radio" name="date" value="{{data}}" required>
{% endfor %}
```

I get the response as

```
"['2022-02-02','2022-02-08']", but i need as 

['2022-02-02','2022-02-08']
```

So how to make radio to button to send data as array

Comment: Which is the frontend framework that you are using?

Comment: All form elements send their data a strings.  If you want anything else it's up to the consuming end to convert to the required datatype.

Comment: django @Nitheesh

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse()`. Take your string, `str` in this case, and do

```
let arr = JSON.parse(str)
```

arr should be your array.

Comment: If you want it back in your original returned form, just do `JSON.stringify(arr)` to get the string version again.